# Not able to establish DB connectivity to hive DB which is hosted in Azure from local

Tags: java, azure, hive, azure-hdinsight, azure-nsg

We have a HdInsight cluster in Azure which is inside a VNet with NSG attached to it. I am trying to connect to Hive DB from DBeaver App. I am getting "Connection reset" error.
[image]

Also when I tried connecting from Java application, getting the same exception.
[image]

We are able to establish connectivity from a web application hosted inside Azure. So added a Inbound & outbound rule to the NSG to allow connection from outside cloud. But still we are facing the same issue.
For testing purpose, I have added source as "Any". Let me know if I am missing anything.
[image]

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you remove `DenyAllInBound`? Also, `AllowVnetInBound` allowed from VirtualNetwork. Are you a java app in the network?

Comment: Custom rule has high priority than DenyAllInBound. So it should allow the connection right? Because of "AllowVnetInBound" only connection is established inside the network.

Comment: network rules look ok. are you sure the hive services are running and on 443 . also can u run the java app on the same box as hive and see if that works if possible.?

Comment: Yes hive service is up. Also connection is established when I try to connect from java app which is running inside Azure. I am able to fetch data from tables. Problem is only from my local